# Why vim-emmet installed in linux can't expand abbreviation in style tag?

Tags: css, linux, vim, emmet

`vim-emmet` installed both in my windows and linux(debian),and same vim configuration file  for them.To create the same `test.hmtl` for windows and linux(debian).

```
cat  test.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        img{
            
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

- In windows:

Open test.html with vim and write w10 in style's img tag.

```
img{
    w10
}
```

The whole `test.html` is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        img{
            w10  
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Then click hot key to expand it , i get:

```
img{
    width : 10px;
}
```

- In linux:

With same steps ,

```
img{
    w10
}
```

expanded into

```
img{
    <w10></w10>
}
```

If i edit a `test.css` in my linux,

```
img{
    w10
}
```

expanded into

```
img{
    width : 10px;
}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: is this part identical on both os?  <style type="text/css">

Comment: All are same in both os.

Comment: then there might be other plugins that prevent emmet from determining the right context? For some reason it behaves like it's in an html context when it should be a css context.